# cURL timeout, can you handle it elegantly?

Tags: php, curl, fatal-error

cURL makes PHP throw a Fatal Error if it takes more than 30 seconds to get a response from the server. This seems to be happening a lot in my web app, particularly if the other server is busy. It really isn't pretty for the user to see that.

I would like to either catch the timeout and display a nice messsage myself, or alternatively, I was wondering if there was a way I could continue with the rest of the PHP script, as the rest of that script can execute even if there is no response from the server (with default values).

I don't really see why cURL would throw a Fatal Error instead of a Warning for the timeout to be honest. It's a real pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase the cURL timeout using these params

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
```

Since you mentioned 30 seconds, i suspect that your PHP Script timeout is running out. So add this to your PHP code.

```
set_time_limit(0);// 0 is infite limit
```

Comment: Aha thanks for that. Being quite new to PHP I wasn't aware that it was PHP itself that allowed a max 30 seconds for the execution of a script. I thought the fatal error was being thrown by curl. Thanks for that, it helps but it's not really the solution I was hoping for.

Comment: Sure, increase the time_limit to infinity when developing, but that's a terrible idea for production.

Comment: This answer doesn't tell you how to catch the error (which is what I'm looking for), it just tells you how to avoid the error. Is it even possible to limit the time for a curl_exec without using that setting?

Answer (score 9):

This is a slightly more literal answer to the question. That is, curl will still stop after 30 seconds, but you can catch the error and keep going if you want.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 40); // prevents 30 seconds from being fatal

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); // curl timeout remains at 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_exec($ch);

if ($error_number = curl_errno($ch)) {
    if (in_array($error_number, array(CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT, CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED))) {
        print "curl timed out";
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

If you have no control over the max_execution_time, you can just lower the curl timeout slightly.